# useState names in developer toolbar

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When using developer tool bar in chrome how do you identify or show the name of the state.When I suddenly switch to hooks the name of my state is not showing anymore

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/1215#issuecomment-479937560

That's the normal behavior for the dev tool when using hooks.

I asked the library author about it, cause I also would like it to show my state variable names.

> @cbdeveloper I haven't thought of a good way for DevTools to be able to display the variable name like you're asking. **DevTools doesn't have a way to read your function's private variables,** and changing the API to support passing in a display name would increase the size of component code. It also just doesn't seem necessary to me, more like a nice to have.
>
> Anyway, this umbrella issue is not the best place to have discussions like this. If you feel strongly about it, I suggest opening a new issue.